# Aggregate rows only if dates range overlap

Tags: sql, mysql, date, aggregate, overlap

I am trying to build a complex sql query for hours but still didn't find any way to do it as expected.

Here is my table and my dataset :

```
create table Skills
(
ID varchar(10),
StartDate date,
EndDate date,
Skill varchar(10)
);

Insert into Skills values
('1','2021-01-01','2021-12-31','A'),
('1','2022-01-01','2022-12-31','B'),
('2','2021-01-01','2021-12-31','A'),
('2','2021-11-30','2022-12-31','B'),
('3','2021-01-01','2021-12-31','A'),
('3','2021-11-30','2022-12-31','B'),
('3','2022-11-30','2023-12-31','C'),
('4','2021-01-01','2021-12-31','A'),
('4','2022-01-01','2022-12-31','B'),
('4','2022-11-30','2023-12-31','C');
```

I would like to aggregate rows by ID only when dates range (StartDate, EndDate) overlap.
Here is the expected result :

```
1, 2021-01-01, 2021-12-31, A
1, 2022-01-01, 2022-12-31, B
2, 2021-01-01, 2022-12-31, B
3, 2021-01-01, 2023-12-31, C
4, 2021-01-01, 2021-12-31, A
4, 2022-01-01, 2023-12-31, C
```

When rows with overlapping dates range are aggregated, we need to keep the oldest StartDate, the newest EndDate and the Skill associated to the newest EndDate.

I tried so many queries with partition by, lag, cte, etc.

Could you help me find the right solution please ?

Thanks,
Regards

Comment: What is MySQL version precisely?

Comment: MySQL version is 8.0

Comment: *and the Skill associated to the newest EndDate* What if 2 rows have the same EndDate but different Skill? What if StartDate is the same too?

Comment: For a same ID you can't have the same StartDate, nor the same EndDate (I mean in my case)

Comment: Does this is provided with according unique indices? if there are such indices then duplicates (include complete ones) MAY EXIST (for example as an issue of some programmatical error or fail), and nothing prevents this. You must take this into account..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *gaps and islands* problem, to solve it you can use `lag()` to determine where the "islands" start, Then use a cumulative `sum()` to determine gaps :

Assuming the `endDate` is unique per `id` :

```
select d.*, s.skill
from (
  select d.id, min(d.start_date) as start_date, max(d.end_date) as end_date
  from (
      select d.*,
      sum(case when DATEDIFF(prev_end_date, start_date) > 0 then 0 else 1 end)  over (partition by id order by start_date) as grp
      from (
            select d.*,
            lag(end_date) over (partition by id order by start_date) as prev_end_date
            from Skills d
      ) d
  ) d
  group by d.id, grp
) d
inner join Skills s on s.id = d.id and s.end_date = d.end_date
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/nAfmelhC)

Comment: Man you so strong, thank you very much, this is doing it perfectly !

Comment: Just find out a little issue with max(Skill) as it will pick the max in alphabetical order instead of the value of Skill from the row with the last EndDate. From my example, if you change ('4','2022-11-30','2023-12-31','C'); by ('4','2022-11-30','2023-12-31','A'); The result will be 'B' instead of 'A'.

Comment: That is correct, let me check

Comment: That's correct, that's what I would have done too, thanks for your answer and your help